# Method of continuity in PDEs

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

Theorem 5.2 (method of continuity) of Gilbarg and Trudinger's "Elliptic partial differential equations of second order" states for $\mathfrak{B}$ a Banach space and $\mathfrak{C}$ a normed linear space, let $L_0$ and $L_1$ be bounded linear operators from $\mathfrak{B}$ into $\mathfrak{C}$. For each $t \in [0,1]$, set $L_t = (1-t)L_0 + tL_1$, and suppose there is a constant $C$ such that
\begin{equation}
\|x\|_\mathfrak{B} \le C \|L_t x\|_\mathfrak{C}
\end{equation}
for $t \in [0,1]$. Then $L_1$ maps $\mathfrak{B}$ onto $\mathfrak{C}$ if and only if $L_0$ maps $\mathfrak{B}$ onto $\mathfrak{C}$.

I would like to apply it to show existence and uniqueness of the problems

1) In Theorem 6.8 of the same book, $L_t u := tLu + (1-t)\Delta u, \quad 0 \le t \le 1$, where
\begin{equation}
Lu = a^{ij}\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j}u + b^i\partial_{x_i}u + cu
\end{equation}
on an open bounded $C^{2,\alpha}$ domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $L$ is strictly elliptic, and the coefficients of $L$ are in $C^\alpha(\overline\Omega)$ with $c \le 0$. The authors said "the operator $L_t$ may be considered a bounded linear operator from a Banach space $\mathfrak{B}_1 := \{u \in C^{2,\alpha}(\overline\Omega) \:|\: u = 0 \text{ on } \partial\Omega \}$ into the Banach space $\mathfrak{B}_2 := C^\alpha(\overline\Omega)$". Why is this operator bounded?

2) In Theorem 6.31 of the same book, we want $\mathfrak{L}_t$ to be one-to-one and onto. Is this equivalent to boundedness?

3) What are some equivalent conditions for showing an operator is bounded? I don't see the use of condition $\|L_t u\|_Y \le C \|u\|_X$ for some Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, what are $L_0$ and $L_1$? Are they not assumed to be bounded operators?

Comment: @MikeMiller I wrote the statement wrong. It should be $L_0$ and $L_1$ to be bounded operators, but I'm not sure how one can show their boundedness.

Comment: Ok. As it currently stands, your question requires I have a copy of Gilbarg & Trudinger to answer, which probably means I won't. You should try to make it self-contained: precisely what do you want to prove, and precisely what are you given as an assumption?

Comment: @MikeMiller I edited my question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: There is a typo in your statement of Theorem 5.2: $L_0$ and $L_1$ map $\mathfrak B$ _onto_ $\mathfrak C$, which is a sneaky way of saying that they are onto mappings. I think it might be helpful for you to do some reading in a functional analysis textbook about bounded, one-to-one, and onto operators between Banach spaces, and to work through some simpler examples to get a feel for the definitions before trying to tackle the method of continuity in Gilbarg and Trudinger. For (1), do you see why $L$ or $\Delta$ are bounded from $\mathfrak B_1$ to $\mathfrak B_2$?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. I edited the statement.

Comment: @miles Thanks for your comments. I got it now.